# Record can't delete in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on an food restaurant system.

I'm a beginner in PHP. I'm having a bit of a problem  deleting a record from the database.When I try to delete a record, it unlink the image , but not deleting the row. How can I solve it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my script::

productlist.php

```
<?php
    $pd = new Product();
    $fm = new Format();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $insertProduct = $pd->productInsert($_POST,$_FILES);
    }
    if(isset($_GET['delpro'])){
        $id = $_GET['delpro'];
        $delpro = $pd->delProById($id);
    }
?>
<div class="grid_10">
    <div class="box round first grid">
        <h2>Post List</h2>
        <div class="block">  
            <table class="data display datatable" id="example">
            <tbody>
            <?php
                $getPd = $pd->getAllProduct();
                if($getPd){
                    $i = 0;
                    while($result = $getPd->fetch_assoc()){
                       $i++;
            ?>
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                    <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['productName'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['catName'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['brandName'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fm->textShorten($result['body'],50);?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['price'];?></td>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" height="40px" width="60px"/></td>
                    <td>
                    <?php 
                        if($result['type'] == 0){
                            echo "Featured";
                        } else{
                            echo "General";
                        }

                    ?></td>
                    <td><a href="productedit.php?proid=<?php echo $result['productId'];?>">Edit</a> || <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete!')" href="?delpro=<?php echo $result['productId'];?>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Product.php

```
public function delProById($id){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE productId = '$id'";
            $getData = $this->db->select($query);
            if($getData){
                while($delImg = $getData->fetch_assoc()){
                    $dellink = $delImg['image']; 
                    unlink($dellink);

                }
            }


            $delquery = "DELETE FROM tbl_product WHERE productId = '$id'";
            $delData = $this->db->delete($query);
            if($delData){
                $msg = "<span class='success'>Product Deleted Successfully</span>";

                return $msg;
            }
            else {
                $msg = "<span class='error'>Product Not Deleted.</span>";
                return $msg;
            }


        }
```

Comment: What database library are you using? Is second file really `productedit.php`?

Comment: Why are you using $_GET to get the product id. That is extremely dangerous in your case. Rather use $_POST

Comment: Your code is subject to sql injection. You should use prepared statements

Comment: @PieterSteyn Both are equally secure

Comment: @PieterSteyn Why do you claim POST is 'safer' than GET?

Comment: @ErwinMoller The app is making a call to the database to delete information from the DB and therefore it is open to malice using $_GET. And notice I used 'in your case'. I didn't make the general claim that one is safer than another

Comment: *".When I try to delete a record, it unlink the image , but not deleting the row"* That about the main reason why you might want to store the file data in the RDMS to keep a valid state... Or alter the code to allow "transactions" between RDMS/file system for that more or less record not deleted ok file also not gets deleted but it can get tricky to get that right.. i believe the more modern ANSI/ISO SQL standards (SQL/MED) has DATALINK datatype defined for that

Comment: @PieterSteyn Still, GET and POST are equally safe. Both can be easily manipulated by the visitor. Both are untrustworth. You are right you warned him about that, but POSTing instead of GETting won't change a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing delete statement using the wrong query. Instead of $query which holds the SELECT statement you should do the following:

```
        $delData = $this->db->delete($delquery);
```

Comment: Yep, to me - $query doesn't exist, therefore it isn't doing anything. $delquery is the variable holding the SQL query.

Comment: He would actually receive an error stating inexistent method. Actually, it just doesn't get deleted, so it looks like there's some kind of wrapper for deleting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what framework you are using (it seems like CodeIgniter or so) but clearly you are trying to run the wrong query.
Try:

```
$delData = $this->db->query($delQuery)
```

instead of

```
$delData = $this->db->delete($query)
```

If the PHP framework is really CodeIgniter (or whatever framework), it is highly discouraged to run raw sql in PHP. 
Please refer to : [CodeIgniter Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are using some class or framework that manages SQL queries to use the select and delete methods.

Just change the query variable name:
$delData = $this->db->delete(**$query**);

to:
$delData = $this->db->delete(**$delquery**);

Answer (score -2):

There is no ->delete function in MySQLi. You're going to just use

```
$this->db->query($query);
```

Each command in SQL is in the line. The calls to the SQL object are only a proxy to the internal database. SQL's library of commands is internal. So we just use the variable, which is the object, now after connecting, and we delete the record(s) brought up by the query itself.